# during testing on postman TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType' is coming

Tags: python, flask, testing

during testing on postman error is coming

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

```
from flask.json import jsonify
from flask import Flask,request,app
from flask import Flask,request

def sum(number1,number2):
    result= number1+number2
    return result

def sub(number1,number2):
    result= number1-number2
    return result
def mul(number1,number2):
    result= number1*number2
    return result

def div(number1,number2):
    result= number1/number2
    return result

app=Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/sum',methods=['POST','GET'])
def main():

    number1=int(request.form.get('number'))
    number2=int(request.form.get('number'))
    result=sum(number1,number2)
    return jsonify(result)

@app.route('/sub',methods=['POST','GET'])
def hello():
    number1=int(request.form.get('number'))
    number2=int(request.form.get('number'))
    result=sub(number1,number2)
    return jsonify(result)

@app.route('/mul',methods=['POST','GET'])
def how():
    number1=int(request.form.get('number'))
    number2=int(request.form.get('number'))
    result=mul(number1,number2)
    return jsonify(result)

@app.route('/sum',methods=['POST','GET'])
def are():
    number1=int(request.form.get('number'))
    number2=int(request.form.get('number'))
    result=div(number1,number2)
    return jsonify(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

`dict.get('KEY')` returns `None` if the lookup key does not exist, so check if the key is correct.

You can assign a default value if the key does not exist like this:

```
request.form.get('number', 1)
```

But in you case I would recommend doing it something like this

```
from flask_api import status
...

try:
   number1=int(request.form['number1'])
   number2=int(request.form['number2'])
   ...
except KeyError:
   return "Invalid Input", status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
```